# Deploying yeoman app to Heroku / Node

Tags: angularjs, node.js, heroku, yeoman

I'm trying to deploy my first yeoman / angular app to Heroku.

I'm using Grunt to build a 'dist' folder and I'm following this tutorial [here](http://davemax.com/heroku-deploy-yeoman-angular-app/) which suggests that I need to have a package.json file within my dist folder.  But when I look in the dist folder I notice that package.json file is not copied there after the build.

Do I need to change my grunt.js file so the package.json file is copied to the dist folder?  Something like this:

```
<!--grunt.js -->

copy: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      dot: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
      src: [
        '*.{ico,png,txt}',
        '.htaccess',
        '*.html',
        'views/{,*/}*.html',
        'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
        'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
        'json/*.json',
        'package.json'  <--- Add in this line ?
      ]
    }
```

The next think I notice is when I try to run `heroku ps:scale web=1`from the command line I get the response

> *'could not find formation'*

So I googled a little and some are suggesting that the Procfile must have no extension.  I've checked both the spelling and to see if the file has no extension and I can't see any problem with it.  Any other reasons why I might see this output?

And finally in the package.json file under the scripts object do I need to add a "start" element?  at the moment I have:

```
  "scripts": {
"test": "grunt test"
```

}

But should I change this to

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/web.js",
    "test": "grunt test"
  }
```

And in my web.js file I have the following:

```
var gzippo = require('gzippo');
var express = require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var app = express();

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(gzippo.staticGzip("" + __dirname + "/dist"));
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

Comment: RE: your Procfile—are you developing on Windows? The file may have an extension you cannot see (you'll have to turn them on in Windows if so).

Comment: No I'm developing on OSX Yosemite